# Truncate first charcter in decimal value silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have decimal property in my class.

```
private decimal? _mon;
public decimal? Mon
{
  get { return _mon;}
  set { 
        if (value != _mon)
        {
             _mon = (decimal?)value;
              OnChanged("Mon");  
        } 
      }
}

private void OnChanged(string prop)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
}
```

I  have datagrid. And I have assigned this property to one of the DataGridTemplateColumn.
That feild is editable. While I edit value **e.g : 4.12**. I have cursor on first digit , I remove 4 (press delete key) than it will automaticaly take 0.12 , I need to change it to .12 only.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

.12 is illegal for decimal type, like you cann't assign string to int.

If you would like to set the presentation value to .12 so you had better to use it as a string object rather then decimal type.

Or you can use the IvalueConverter interface in your project to convert the presentation value to the actual value you want, probably decimal type.

Comment: I need for display purpose it should be .12 not 0.12 only

Comment: Or is there any other way to focus first digit of textbox value

Comment: For presentation purpose only you have a special silverlight 'tool' for this specific reason, it calls "IValueConverter" interface, you can read about this here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29621/The-Last-IValueConverter

Comment: This interface gives you the ability to present object whatever you like but to assign to a different object type. The (very) simple one is presenting an int value as string and assign it back to the int from the presentation view.